# About c++ input behavior

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int ArrSize = 400;

int main()
{
   char arr1[ArrSize];
   char arr2[ArrSize];
   char arr3[ArrSize];

   cout << "enter the first string ";
   cin >> arr1;
   cout << "enter the second string ";
   cin.get(arr2, ArrSize);
   cout << "enter the thrid string ";
   cin>>arr3;


   cout << endl << endl;

   cout << "first string is: " << arr1 << "\n";
   cout << "second string is:  " << arr2 << "\n";
   cout << "thrid string is:  " << arr3 << "\n";

   return 0;
}
```

execution result is

input :
"abc\n"

output :
first string is: abc
second string is:
thrid string is:(strange characters)

Can you explain why the second cin didn't get input?

I expected that cin would read leading white spaces form the stream buffer and ignore them and read new string.

Comment: I don't understand what precisely you typed into the program. Please use a list and make clear what constitutes output and input.

Comment: input : "abc\n"

Comment: output: arr1 = "abc", arr2 = "", arr3=trash values

Comment: Sorry I edited it

Comment: Are you aware of why `arr2` is empty? You're just asking about `arr3`?

Comment: I'm asking about arr3

Comment: Sorry I'm asking for both arr2 and arr3

Comment: And second cin failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by adjusting the program to check for errors.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int ArrSize = 400;

int main()
{
   char arr1[ArrSize];
   char arr2[ArrSize];
   char arr3[ArrSize];

   cout << "enter the first string ";
   if (!(cin >> arr1))
   {
       cout << "Failed cin >> arr1\n";
   }
   cout << "enter the second string ";
   if (!cin.get(arr2, ArrSize))
   {
       cout << "Failed cin.get(arr2, ArrSize)\n";
   }
   cout << "enter the third string ";
   if (!(cin>>arr3))
   {
       cout << "Failed cin >> arr3\n";
   }
   cout << endl << endl;

   cout << "first string is: " << arr1 << "\n";
   cout << "second string is:  " << arr2 << "\n";
   cout << "third string is:  " << arr3 << "\n";

   return 0;
}
```

The results should be something like

```
enter the first string abc
enter the second string Failed cin.get(arr2, ArrSize)
enter the third string Failed cin >> arr3


first string is: abc
second string is:  
third string is:  <garbage here>
```

We can see that the second and third reads failed. Why is that? To find out, we need to do a little reading. Here's some high-quality [documentation for `std::istream::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)

The relevant overload is number 3, but 3 just calls number 4 with the delimiter set to `'\n'` and 4 says two important things,

> Characters are extracted and stored until any of the following occurs:
>
> - `count-1` characters have been stored
> - end of file condition occurs in the input sequence (`setstate(eofbit)` is called)
> - the next available input character c equals `delim`, as determined by `Traits::eq(c, delim)`. This character is not extracted (unlike `basic_istream::getline()`)

> If no characters were extracted, calls `setstate(failbit)`. In any case, if count>0, a null character (CharT() is stored in the next successive location of the array.

So if you only get a newline, delim in this case, the output string `arr2` is null terminated and the stream is placed into fail state because no characters were extracted from the stream, making the stream unreadable until the failure is acknowledged by clearing it. This is what we are seeing: an empty string and fail bit.

Why is the string empty? Why didn't it prompt for input? Because `cin >> arr1` reads one whitespace-delimited token from the stream. It will ignore all whitespace up to the start of the token, but it leaves the whitespace after the token in the stream.

If you type abc and hit enter, "abc\n" goes into the stream. `cin >> arr1` reads "abc" into `arr1`. The "\n" stays in the stream where `cin.get(arr2, ArrSize)` finds it. The `get` exit condition is immediately satisfied by the "\n", so `get` stops and leaves the "\n" in the stream. No characters were extracted. Fail bit is set and `arr2` is null terminated.

`cin>>arr3` subsequently fails because you can't read from a failed stream. Nothing is placed in `arr3`, so when `arr3` is printed, it is unterminated and `<<` keeps printing until it finds a terminator. This is the garbage characters, though [technically anything can happen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

The question does not specify what is to be done with data left over after `cin >> arr1`. Common solutions are to remove everything up to and including the newline character from the stream with

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

but if you want to use any characters left on the line for `arr2`, you'll have to be trickier. For example, always read lines, build an `istringstream` out of the line, and then parse the `istringstream` as is done [in option 2 of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/4581301).

Side note: Reading into character arrays with `>>` is always risky because it will keep reading until whitespace is found. If the program reads the size of the array from the stream without finding whitepace, [sucks to be you](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). `get` knows to stop before its overflowed. `>>` doesn't. On the other hand, `get` will read until it finds the end of the line, not just a single whitespace delimited token.

`>>` into a `std::string` will do the right thing and resize the `string` to fit the input. Generally prefer `std::string` to `char` arrays. And if you are using `std::string` prefer [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to `get` or `istream`'s `getline`.